# Extending peewee expressions throws 'Expression' object is not iterable

Tags: python, peewee

I want to dynamically create where-clauses in peewee. I learned I need to use expressions, but cannot get this to run. Here my code:

```
  clauses = [
    (Docs.language_frst == 0), 
    (Docs.body_len <= max_body_len),
    (Docs.body_len >= min_body_len)
  ]

  if len(aValid_ids_used):
    clauses.extend( (Docs.id.not_in(aValid_ids_used)) )

  docids = Docs.select(Docs.id).where(reduce(operator.and_, clauses))
```

As long as aValid_ids_used is empty the code runs fine. Once aValid_ids_used is not empty any longer and I am asking the clauses to be extended I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "xyz.py", line 170, in <module>
clauses.extend( (Docs.id.not_in(aValid_ids_used)) ) 
TypeError: 'Expression' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list to extend with. You're currently passing an `Expression`

```
clauses.extend( (Docs.id.not_in(aValid_ids_used), ) )
```

e.g.

```
>>> c = []
>>> c.extend((2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> c.extend((2,))
>>> c
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `list.append` rather than `list.extend`.  `extend` takes a list as an argument, while `append` takes a single item.